# How to access config from parent package in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm in a situation where I have various packages.

Package A has a dependency on Package B.

Package B deals with some core functionality for dealing with an API.

I need Package B to use config options from Package A, but, Package B needs to be flexible, so it could be added to Package C, in a different project.

With Package A and C having unique package names and config options, how can I access those from Package B.

NB - The options will have the same name, but obv they will be published as `package_a.config_option_1` and `package_c.config_option_1`

Comment: I think these configs should be put in your laravel config folder and your packages get the configs there instead.

Comment: I am doing that. But, Package A config is in `package-a.php` and Package C in `package-c.php`. Package B needs to reference _either_, dynamically.

Comment: I can't give a full answer, just a comment. In this case I would make a factory that determines which package configuration the application should use, and creates a configuration array for package B. Package B in this situation does not have to think about what configuration to use. Because the configuration of the parent packages is the same, it will simply work with what the factory will give it.